# Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, user-management

I am running Fedora 12 and I've setup a partition separate from my root partition to keep shared files and home directories.

Now, I've been having permission issues where it says the user cannot chdir into their home directory (/files/home/*). Now, I fixed this originally by chmodding / to 0755 and the home directories also to 0755. And yes, the user is the owner:group of their home directory.

Now get this, I didn't change a thing, rebooted, everything still works. Great, right? I boot the server up a day later, and now same ol issue. This is a home server that wasn't on at all at any point in between the working state and non-working state. Also, nothing else was modified.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

== edit ==

Ok. So I've narrowed it down to an SELinux issue. If I run "setenforce 0" everything is fine. However, I'd prefere to keep SELinux enabled. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is a "non-standard" location for home directories. You can change the policy of that box to label these directories correctly, then everything should work like expected.

Assuming that I understood your problem correctly, the commands to change the policy would
be

```
 semanage fcontext -a -t home_root_t "/files/home"
```

This should tell the system that this is a root dir for home directories.
With

```
 restorecon -r /file/home
```

should do the relabeling then. The directories in /files/home should have the user_home_dir_t context, the normal files in the home dir user_home_t.

HTH. Look at the [SELinux Docs](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/index.html).